# Provisioning profile use existing certificate doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios8, certificate

I want to use push notifications.

What I have done so far:
- Generated App ID
- Enabled Push Notification for this App ID
- Generated Development Certificate for Push Notification

Now I want to generate a provisioning profil.
I can see my generated Certificate in the member center, but I can't use it to generate a promising profile. It always wants me to generate a new certificate. I can't select an existing one...

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate you generated is not intended for generating provisioning profiles, it is for authenticating your push server with apple's push notification service (APNS).

You only need to regenerate your current development provisioning profile to pick up the development push notification entitlement (even that may not be necessary!).

The same applies for production push certificates and provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

When you are building app with push notification, you need to have two certificate.

So the reason is because you don't have certificate for your provision.

Once you have created your app ID, please create iOS App Development certificate, and when you are generating development provision file select that certificate.

Also, you need to generate one more certificate for Push Notification and it will be used to generate pem file that is needed for server side push.